# Trying to calculate x*y through constructor instance cal . How can i modify code to make sample constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var sample = (x,y) => (this.x =x, this.y = y, console.log(x*y));
var cal = new sample();
cal(12,5);
```

Getting the error in console TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined .

Comment: `sample is not a constructor`

Comment: trying to calculate x*y through constructor instance cal . How can i modify code to change it in constructor ?

Comment: but sample isn't a constructor - you can't do that with arrow functions - arrow functions are cool ... but they aren't always the best tool for the job - use a regular function or if you want to remain cool, use `class sample`

Comment: try `var sample = function(x,y) { this.x =x; this.y = y; console.log(x*y); };`

Comment: Which browser gives the error you describe? (is *babelfied* code that gives that error?)

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions cannot be used as class structures. However the definition you have there will work perfectly fine as a function on it's own. Simply remove the `new sample()` reference and your code will probably run as expected:

```
var cal = (x,y) => (console.log(x*y));
cal(12,5)
```

I removed the storing of `this.x` and `this.y` as it will be binding to the this of the outer function, not an inner context. This is likely not a side effect you intend and is something that you want to be careful about when working with arrow functions.